# Why big array java is slow

Tags: java, arrays, garbage-collection

I created an array of a class with big length, ~150M elements, sorted by key (describe bellow). Then I build a simple http server to feedback each request as a binary search function on the array. (I'm sure the server's work is fine)

Data initiation is just fine (ofcouse quite slow). Binary search function is fast as expected.

The problem is: the respond is just fast for a while (10mins, 1 hours... many kind of time range), then server take quite long (some minutes) to do binary search function for a request, then it's fast back, then slow after a while...
While it's slow, I check server status (htop), it seems like jvm is in GC.

The problem is not happened when I split big array into smaller ones, for ex: 10 arrays of 15M elements, I find the target array before do searching on. So I guess something happens in JVM when I create too large array

(Edit: I have no problem on spliting big array into pieces because I implemented the "SiteInfo" object to native, big amount of objects in JVM is decreased. So the problem caused by too many objects I created as replies bellow, thank you guys)

Guys do you have any idea for my problem?

(I posted my code, there's some Pseudocode that I think it's not really important)

```
public static class Token2TopSite implements Comparable<Token2TopSite> {

    public final String token; // this is key for binary search
    public final SiteInfo[] topSites; // just data, not important at this question, I think

    public Token2TopSite(String token, SiteInfo[] topSites) {
        this.token = token;
        this.topSites = topSites;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Token2TopSite o) {
        return token.compareTo(o.token);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Token2TopSite[] array = new Token2TopSite[150 * 1000000];
        ...; // init data for array, this runs properly
        Arrays.sort(array);
        startServerOnArray(array); // each request is a element search on the array
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a tricky area.  Arrays are usually very fast, but there can be some edge cases.  For example, what happens when the JVM decides to relocate the big array within the heap?  Add -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -XX:+PrintSafepointStatistics -XX:PrintSafepointStatisticsCount=1 -XX:+PrintGCDetails.  That will help you to rule out a stop the world/GC problem going on.  Let us know what it says.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think Omry Yadan's diagnosis is probably correct.  These sound like GC pauses, and they are likely to be particularly bad if you have huge numbers of long-lived reachable objects in the heap.  The GC has to traverse all of the live objects when doing a "full" collection.

(You can confirm that this is *really* a GC-related problem by enabling GC logging, and comparing the times when your server performance is slow with the GC events.)

However, I disagree with his suggested solution.

Rather than rewriting the application, a simpler solution is to configure the JVM to use a "concurrent" or "low pause" garbage collector.  It is just a matter of setting some parameters on the command that that starts your webserver's JVM.

Here are some Oracle references:

- [Garbage Collection Basics](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html).
- [HotSpot VM Options](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html)
- [Java HotSpot Garbage Collection](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-140228.html)

Comment: This by no means explains why splitting into 10 arrays of 15M helps.

Comment: Stephen C is right, I think. I checked that's Gc. Because of I created too many object in Jvm. Some tuning of Gc help me quite much, but the problem still happened sometime. I went natively code on every object (as possible), then it worked smoothly. Of course going native is too time-expensive :(

@maaartinus: I edited my post, I had natively implemented the SiteInfo object so big amount of object were decreased, so it worked, but rarely sometime it still hang on, I detected that by automatic request

Answer (score 1):

The JVM does not work well when there are more than 10s of millions of objects.
the reason is that the garbage collector, when looking for free memory - needs to traverse all your objects if it does not find anything to free.
one solution is to use less objects.
I wrote a primitive collections library called [Banana](https://github.com/omry/banana) that does it's own memory management.
it basically creates a single (or several) int array (int[]) and let you build dynamic data structures on top of that (several are already implemented, HashTable, LinkedList, LRUCache and more).

Comment: You're right that going natively is very good. I didn't try Banana. I used fast util library (from apache) instead with some Gc parametters tuning, it worked for me

Comment: I guess you are still at the low end of the problem.
test the scalability of your solution, see how it behaves when you double your data size (if you have enough RAM for that).
Banana is actually pure Java, no native code there (Although I am considering adding support for Unsafe BlockAllocator).

Comment: Maybe I said not so clearly about "native" terms. I meant about data structure, fast util lib helped me. My problems is the creation of too many object, for example too many object A {field1, ..., fieldN}. Infact field number i has a limitation of values, so I converted List<A> info N arrays.
Arrays number i is native type (int, long...) hold the ids, point to the real objects of field i.
Finally total objects I create is sum(possible values of field-i) + N arrays reference, it's much fewer than the big amount of class A's generation